# What is the best way to work with multiple files in multithread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I am creating a Windows Form application, where I select a folder that contains multiple *.txt files. Their length may vary from few thousand lines (kB) to up to 50 milion lines (1GB). Every line of the code has three informations. Date in long, location id in int and value in float all separated by semicolon (;). I need to calculate min and max value in all those files and tell in which file it is, and then the most frequent value.

I already have these files verified and stored in an arraylist. I am opening a thread to read the files one by one and I read the data by line. It works fine, but when there are 1GB files, I run out of memory. I tried to store the values in dictionary, where key would be the date and the value would be an object that contains all the info loaded from the line alongside with the filename. I see I cannot use a dictionary, because at about 6M values, I ran out of memory. So I should probably do it in multithread. I though I could run two threads, one that reads the file and puts the info in some kind of container and the other that reads from it and makes calculations and then deletes the values from the container. But I don't know which container could do such thing. Moreover I need to calculate the most frequent value, so they need to be stored somewhere which leads me back to some kind of dictionary, but I already know I will run out of memory. I don't have much experience with threads either, so I don't know what is possible. Here is my code so far:

GUI:

```
namespace STI {
    public partial class GUI : Form {
        private String path = null;
        public static ArrayList txtFiles;

        public GUI() {
            InitializeComponent();
            _GUI1 = this;
        }

       //I run it in thread. I thought I would run the second 
       //one here that would work with the values inputed in some container
        private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ThreadDataProcessing processing = new ThreadDataProcessing();
            Thread t_process = new Thread(processing.runProcessing);
            t_process.Start();

            //ThreadDataCalculating calculating = new ThreadDataCalculating();
            //Thread t_calc = new Thread(calculating.runCalculation());
            //t_calc.Start();

        }


    }
}
```

ThreadProcessing.cs

```
namespace STI.thread_package {
    class ThreadDataProcessing {
        public static Dictionary<long, object> finalMap = new Dictionary<long, object>();

        public void runProcessing() {
            foreach (FileInfo file in GUI.txtFiles) {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file.FullName.ToString(), FileMode.Open))
                using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs)) {
                    String line;
                    String[] splitted;
                    try { 
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                            splitted = line.Split(';');

                            if (splitted.Length == 3) {
                                long date = long.Parse(splitted[0]);
                                int location = int.Parse(splitted[1]);
                                float value = float.Parse(splitted[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                                Entry entry = new Entry(date, location, value, file.Name);

                                if (!finalMap.ContainsKey(entry.getDate())) {
                                    finalMap.Add(entry.getDate(), entry);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        GUI._GUI1.update("File \"" + file.Name + "\" completed\n");
                    }
                    catch (FormatException ex) {
                        GUI._GUI1.update("Wrong file format.");
                    }
                    catch (OutOfMemoryException) {
                        GUI._GUI1.update("Out of memory");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the object in which I put the values from lines:
Entry.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace STI.entities_package {
    class Entry {
        private long date;
        private int location;
        private float value;
        private String fileName;
        private int count;

        public Entry(long date, int location, float value, String fileName) {
            this.date = date;
            this.location = location;
            this.value = value;
            this.fileName = fileName;

            this.count = 1;
        }

        public long getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public int getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: TL; DR; [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Multithreading is certainly not going to help you here, because introducing more threads does not magically add more memory to your process. Edit the question so that any mention of multithreading is removed. Also remove the GUI code, since that's not the problem.

Comment: Running out of memory is a rather silly problem to have these days, modern computers have a lot of it.  A terabyte is very easy to come by and does not cost any money either.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting to AnyCPU, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option when you see it.  You don't prefer it.

Comment: I already cleared up the code. Well shouldn't be there any kind of multithreading? Like i said If I could read from a container in one thread and simultaneously write in it new values, it would "give me more memory" since I don't have to store those things anymore right? But then there is a problem with the frequency.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean? All objects have limit of 2GB size in both 32b and 64b. I am reffering to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657181/very-large-collection-in-net-causes-out-of-memory-exception). Also the computer I should run this app is not modern at all. It has Intel Core 2 Duo L7500 with 3GB Ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that multithreading is going to help you here - it could help you separate the IO-bound tasks from the CPU-bound tasks, but your CPU-bound tasks are so trivial that I don't think they warrant their own thread.  All multithreading is going to do is unnecessarily increase the problem complexity.

Calculating the min/max in constant memory is trivial: just maintain a minFile and maxFile variable that gets updated when the current file's value is less-than minFile or greater-than maxFile.  Finding the most frequent value is going to require more memory, but with only a few million files you ought to have enough RAM to store a `Dictionary<float, int>` that maintains the frequency of each value, after which you iterate through the map to determine which value had the highest frequency.  If for some reason you don't have enough RAM (make sure that your files are being closed and garbage collected if you're running out of memory, because a `Dictionary<float, int>` with a few million entries ought to fit in less than a gigabyte of RAM) then you can make multiple passes over the files: on the first pass store the values in a `Dictionary<interval, int>` where you've split up the interval between MIN_FLOAT and MAX_FLOAT into a few thousand sub-intervals, then on the next pass you can ignore all values that didn't fit into the interval with the highest frequency thus shrinking the dictionary's size.  However, the `Dictionary<float, int>` ought to fit into memory, so unless you start processing billions of files instead of millions of files you probably won't need a multi-pass procedure.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I will try it out. You are right that I could store the values in a dictionary, because even though the largest file has about 45M lines, there probably won't be that many unique values, so the dictionary could fit the limit instead of storing every line in there. Btw. there are not that many files. I have around 5-7 files, they just differ in size.

Comment: @Arcane Gotcha, I thought it was one file per value